# Audioplayers: Wireless headphone connection doesn't work on iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

When I start playing a media URL with [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers), the music starts both on `Android` and `iOS`. When I connect a pair of wireless headphones (Airpods) the output channel is switched to the headphone as expected.

However on `iOS` the device speakers continue playing the music instead of the headphones. The headphones are paired in both cases, other apps and system sounds are put through.

Is there something I'm missing about the `AudioContextIOS` in `audioContext`?
Any help or advice is much appreciated!

Sample code of my `audioContext` settings:

```
 AudioPlayer controller = AudioPlayer();

 final audioContext = AudioContext(
   android AudioContextAndroid(
     audioFocus: AndroidAudioFocus.gain,
     isSpeakerphoneOn: true,
     contentType:AndroidContentType.music,
     usageType: AndroidUsageType.media,
     stayAwake: true,
   ),
   iOS: AudioContextIOS(
     category: AVAudioSessionCategory.soloAmbient,
     defaultToSpeaker: true,
     options: [
       AVAudioSessionOptions.allowBluetoothA2DP,
       AVAudioSessionOptions.defaultToSpeaker,
     ],
   ),
 );

 controller.setAudioContext(audioContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in [this](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/pull/1563) PR.

I've upgraded from version 4.1.0 to 5.2.0 and it is working great.